# Why is`FOR XML XXX` required to perform a HASHBYTES in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.BATCH WHERE batch_key = 22866 FOR XML AUTO))
```

It works fine.

But the following query:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.BATCH WHERE batch_key = 22866 ))
```

returns the following error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Why is `FOR XML XXX` required to perform a hash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186183/hash-a-sql-row/38745587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't. However, `HASHBYTES` requires a single scalar value as its input; You have a result set containing multiple rows/columns and `FOR XML` is one of *many* different ways to reduce such a result set down to a single scalar value.