# Checking for data equivalence between SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've built a script to migrate specific tables from one database to another and it's been working great- but I'd like to make it more efficient. It does a lot of needless work truncating and migrating the data where both the target and source database tables were already identical. I'm wondering if theres something like a hash function that could be run for an entire table on both the source and target databases to determine if everything is 100% identical between the two tables? I'm only caring about the data here, I don't need to check for schema differences.

Comment: You could do it at the record level, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186246/1260204

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server ships with a utility for this: [tablediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=The%20tablediff%20utility%20is%20used%20to%20compare%20the,a%20batch%20file%20to%20perform%20the%20following%20tasks%3A).

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the top comment but there are many databases across multiple servers some with unique VPN requirements. The script acts as a bit of a proxy so that each database only needs to be able to talk to and from the machine running the script and not worry about communicating with each other.

Comment: Then run `tablediff` from that central machine.  It connects to a "source" and "destination" server to perform the comparison.

Comment: True, I'll see what it takes to get this integrated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio there's a built in Data Comparison tool which you might find useful.  To automate a migration script you could compare the source table to an empty table (with the same definition) and accept all changes.

In a SQL project within VS under Tools> SQL Server> New Data Comparison...

[image]