# Method to evaluate the probability of false negatives arising from different uses of TSQL BINARY_CHECKSUM()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table of about 400,000 rows and 13 columns. The columns are a mix of data types (dates, GUIDs, varchars, text) and a variety of cardinalities (five low cardinality, eight high). In using `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` to attempt to detect changes on each row, I want to compare the probability of a change not being detected for single `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` function with all 13 columns, versus splitting the columns across two `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` functions.

Additional processing overhead for two vs one is negligible (subtree cost 18.7 vs 17.5).

This exercise doesn't have to perfectly detect all changes. A "small" miss rate is tolerable. The hypothesis I want to test is: For almost no extra CPU effort in splitting the checksum calc, will I go from a "small" miss rate, to an "infinitesimally small" miss rate, or will the difference be negligible?

```
  DECLARE @now as datetime2(0) = sysdatetime();
       IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_bin_ckecksum') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #my_bin_ckecksum;
   SELECT tbl.ID
          ,BINARY_CHECKSUM(GUID1, GUID2, Date1, Date2, varchar1, Date3, varchar2, varchar3, varchar4, GUID3, Date4, Text1, varchar5) as BinaryChecksum
          ,@now as Checkdate
     INTO #my_bin_ckecksum
     FROM dbo.my_table tbl
;

       IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_bin_ckecksum2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #my_bin_ckecksum2;
   SELECT tbl.ID
--------- Will splitting into two binary checksums reduce the chance of not detecting a change, where a change has, in fact, occurred.
          ,BINARY_CHECKSUM(GUID1, GUID2, Date1, Date2, varchar1, Date3)                 as BinaryChecksum1
          ,BINARY_CHECKSUM(varchar2, varchar3, varchar4, GUID3, Date4, Text1, varchar5) as BinaryChecksum2
          ,@now as Checkdate
     INTO #my_bin_ckecksum2
     FROM dbo.my_table tbl
;
```

Comment: If you want to detect changes, why not use CT/CDC? (also consider adding a `rowversion` column)

Comment: Let's assume for the purposes of this exercise that they are not options. It's not about "wanting to detect changes" it's about evaluating the effectiveness of different uses of the BINARY_CHECKSUM() function.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using `binary_checksum`? I would tend to use a constuct like `select hashbytes('MD5', concat_ws('|', col1, col2, [...]))`. Hashbytes has the same null-handling characteristic, slower, and with lower chance of collision. MD5 is deprecated as of SQL 2016, but faster than non-deprecated algorithms and easily "good enough" most of the time. You can always switch algorithms once you absolutely have to. As to your particular question, I don't think there's any way, certainly no trivial way, to reliably compute the probability difference for arbitrary data.

Comment: @allmhuran Thank you! I'll dig into hashbytes a bit more. I've been testing my hypothesis with contrived randomised data that vaguely mimics the real data. What's become apparent is that (the way I'm doind it) millions of comparisons isn't enough. It's probably going to require many billions to get a reliable pattern. Not looking promising :-(

Comment: 'In using BINARY_CHECKSUM() to attempt to detect changes', 'It's not about "wanting to detect changes"'. I'm getting mixed messages. Also, in re the "hashbytes/concat_ws", ⚠️. Check out [this article](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/07/02/sql-finding-rows-that-have-changed-in-t-sql-checksum-binary_checksum-hashbytes/) for a much better exposition than I'd be able to give here.

Comment: @benthul Thank you, point taken. the question not *primarily* about wanting to detect changes. The options suggested by Dai are not available in this case, and BINARY_CHECKSUM() is *probably* good enough. If splitting the comparson across two function calls is significantly reduces the chance of a change not being detected, then it seems a better option. Proving it, one way or the other seems to be the hard thing though.

Comment: I'd still use the hashbytes approach, just not with concat_ws. As to why hashbytes over binary_checksum() comes down to math. Using the Birthday Problem, I calculate the number of elements that you'd need to have a 50% probability of a collision in a 32-bit space (i.e. the range for binary_checksum()) to be 54563. Running the same calculation for SHA2-256 gives me something in the range of 2e38. Strengthening the reliability of the latter to 99.9% still gives me 1e37. That's a lot of room in your domain space, especially when compared with what binary_checksum can provide.

Comment: Great comment @BenThul. Many thanks. I read Greg Low's article that you recommended and it made a lot of sense and pointed out some gotchas. For anyone else wondering about the "Birthday Problem" you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: That's true, if you have a couple (or more) nullable columns, it's possible for two different rows to produce the same concatenation with `concat_ws` if the nullable columns are sequential in the concatenation, eg {a, null, b} => a|b, and {null, a, b} also => a|b. It's rare, but a possible concern, depending on your schema. If your schema could possibly produce this scenario, you would have to use a solution that always adds the separator character, which solves the problem (the results in this example would be different then: a||b vs |a|b.

Comment: See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zTNhS3MF). It shows several `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` collisions with just some simple data.  Judging from the result, the algorithm appears to be a combination of 4-bit shifts and exclusive-or's. The goal was likely to be as computationally simple as possible. The MD5 algorithm is better, but computationally more costly. You still have to be careful how you combine your data. For example `('ab', 'cd|ef')` might yield the same result as `('ab|cd', 'ef')`

Comment: I'll second the sentiment: don't use BINARY_CHECKSUM, it has bitten me many times :( I use CONCAT(field1, '_', field2, '_'... fieldN) and it works much better

Answer (score 0):

**BLUF:** You can use `SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', (SELECT D.* FOR XML RAW)) AS Hash FROM Data D` to calculate a reliable hash for most tables.

*Skip to the **Addendum** below, which may be simpler than my initial post here.*

Just to toss out what I believe may be a reliable column hash algorithm: The following uses a repeating expression to generate (what I believe to be) a unique binary string to be fed into the hash, eliminating source-data driven collisions within the scope of a given table definition. This just leaves the collision probability up to the size of the hash result.

**Disclaimer:** I just put this together and have done minimal testing, but I believe it is sound.

```
SELECT D.*, H.Hash
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 0x) -- Empty binary
    + CASE
      WHEN Col1 IS NULL
      THEN 0x00
      ELSE 0x01 + CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DATALENGTH(Col1)) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Col1)
      END
    + CASE
      WHEN Col2 IS NULL
      THEN 0x00
      ELSE 0x01 + CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DATALENGTH(Col2)) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Col2)
      END
    -- Repeat for all columns
    AS Binary
) B
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', B.Binary) AS Hash
) H
```

For fixed-length fields, the DATALENGTH() part could be excluded, and for non-nullable fields, the null indicator (0x00/0x01) could be dropped. Leaving them just makes the binary a bit longer, and it may be easier just to leave them to make code generation simpler.

**ADDENDUM:**

I should have done a more thorough search earlier. This [*hash a SQL row?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186183/) article has an answer that suggests an XML-based approach for feeding the hash function that simplifies things greatly.

I have adapted it below:

```
SELECT D.*, H.Hash, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY H.HASH) AS Count
FROM Data2 D
CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT (
         SELECT
             -- Chose columns (excludes Id). CLR types require conversion.
             D.Value,
             D.Text,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), D.Geo, 1)) AS Geo,
             D.Guid
         FOR XML RAW
     ) AS Xml
) X
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', X.Xml) AS Hash
) H
ORDER BY D.Id
```

If you wish to hash all columns, and all of the columns are basic types supported by `FOR XML` (no CLR types), you can just `SELECT D.* FOR XML RAW` in the inner query. The XML and Hash computations can also just be  moved to the main select.

```
SELECT D.*, HASHBYTES('MD5', (SELECT D.* FOR XML RAW)) AS Hash
FROM Data D
ORDER BY Hash
```

Sample results:

| Id | Value | Text | Geo | Guid | Hash | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | null | null | 0xE0783CF648050CD19BFA8EDDAE2240C4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | AAA | POINT (1 1) | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | 0x15EE7BF6C8731A6C60BAC0DD10A677B0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | AAA | POINT (1 1) | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | 0x15EE7BF6C8731A6C60BAC0DD10A677B0 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | AAAA | POINT (1 1) | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | 0xED797AB329CCC21DE55A958DA349BCEC | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | AAA | POINT (1 2) | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | 0x210923F03670AAABE9308C872E2352CE | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | AAA | POINT (1 1) | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112 | 0x23C3A8E71CC6133D108B6F35DF3ACF42 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | null | null | null | 0x830191FF1DD77C1DFFCF4821AAB5824E | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |  | null | null | 0x42D664D65266D448ED20A767F31731B2 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |  | null | null | 0x6886A5AB11BFA2CF0DB564D2FF2B1D11 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | null | POINT (1 1) | null | 0x738206EDDE626A361D81103E0E69215F | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | null | POLYGON EMPTY | null | 0x9A5EE4CD906B7B2304CE5F5AA94B727A | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | null | null | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 0x43E8690AD0D506B7E32B22CE4B2CB8EE | 1 |
| 13 | 2 | null | null | 10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 0xFC770F6DCED1E883F4966CB50170FCC8 | 1 |
| 14 | 3 | AAA | POINT (2 2) | a3b6392b-fb68-4e59-a774-039549a53348 | 0xC452628A6DFD4CB94D0799AF41DFC877 | 1 |

(The Id and Count columns are not included in the hash calculation.)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C3L74wgZ).